# 500 internal server error on Tomcat7 while trying to do ajax getJson or post operation in jQuery + Struts2

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, tomcat, struts2

[SOLVED] Name of action turned out to be case sensitive

I want to do an ajax request to server in order to get a JSON. I am using struts2 package configured in this way

```
<package name="it.polito.ai.e3" namespace=""
    extends="struts-default,json-default">
    <action name="getDay" class="it.polito.ai.e3.GetDayAction" >
        <result name="success" type="json" />
        <result name="error" type="json" />
    </action>
</package>
```

GetDayAction class is

```
package it.polito.ai.e3;

import java.util.Date;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GetDayAction extends ActionSupport
{
private String startDate;

public String execute()
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Ciao");
        System.out.println(startDate);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Action.ERROR;
    }

    return Action.SUCCESS;
}

public String getStartDate()
{
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(String startDate)
{
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

}
```

jQuery post block is

```
$(function() {
    $.post('getday.action', document.getElementById('startDate').innerHTML,
        function(data) {

        });  
});
```

in case of get jQuery block is

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('getday.action', document.getElementById('startDate').innerHTML,
        function(data) {

        });  
});
```

`document.getElementById('startDate').innerHTML` gets a Date formatted in a string.

When it executes get or post via ajax, Tomcat gives me 500 internal server error and this stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.getErrorMessage(StrutsActionProxy.java:69)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:500)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
```

Tomcat7 console doesn't show up anything, neither System.out.println() nor other messages.

I have no clue about what I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Does it even execute the code in execute() method?

Comment: Oh I forgot to write, it doesn't even print anything on tomcat console, so I think code in execute() is not being executed.

Comment: It looks like a configuration error or something. What version of Struts r u using?

Comment: Version of struts2 is struts-2.3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` parameter of the `$.post()/$.getJSON()` functions either has to be an object, or a URL parameter string; you can't just pass it a single value and expect it to know what to do with it. So, either:

```
$.getJSON('getday.action', { yourparam : document.getElementById('startDate').innerHTML},
    function(data) {

    });
```

or

```
$.getJSON('getday.action', 'yourparam=' + document.getElementById('startDate').innerHTML},
    function(data) {

    });
```

Comment: This was an error. By the way I've found the solution: I was calling action 'getday' and not 'getDay' as I called it in struts.xml. Thanks for your help.