# Accessing Detailed logs in Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logging

while executing a small application in Eclipse, I get an Http Status 500 error from the Tomcat server that I am running through Eclipse itself...

```
HTTP Status 500 -   

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------  

type Exception report  

message   

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.  

exception   

java.lang.NullPointerException  
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.getErrorMessage   (StrutsActionProxy.java:69)  
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)  
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)  
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)  
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)  
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:500)  
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)  


 note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.8 logs.
```

This message from the server says that error was caused by a "NullPointerException". The last line says that "full stack trace is available in Apache Tomcat/7.0.8 logs.
I have checked the logs created in my workspace ( ${catalina.base} is set to a folder in my workspace) but the logs don't provide any details about the "NullPointerException". The only thing present in the logs is...

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/May/2012:15:19:16 +0530] "GET /KurniawanChap02Struts/ HTTP/1.1" 500 1789
```

I have also tried increasing the "logging levels" but even that doesn't help. 
What should I do to access the detailed logs of the server ?

Comment: You actually seem to *have* the traceback and the line# - that should be enough to get you started.  It's entirely possible your Struts application might be logging to a different file.  Check your log4j.properties file (if you have one).

Comment: possible duplicate of [500 internal server error on Tomcat7 while trying to do ajax getJson or post operation in jQuery + Struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451269/500-internal-server-error-on-tomcat7-while-trying-to-do-ajax-getjson-or-post-ope)

Comment: @paulsm4, its not a duplicate of that post because I want to know about the log files where the detailed information regarding the exception is given. Thanks.

Comment: Is this the catalina.out log file?  It would appear that this is one of the access log files (the name escapes me at the moment).

Comment: Yup, thats correct. The excerpt shown above is from a localhost_access_log file. The files for all the handlers are being generated but none of them contains information about the "NullPointerException" stated above. I even tried to set the logging levels to "ALL" but get the same result. Where should I search for the "NullPointerException" ?

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar errors when I was using different versions of Apache Commons. For getting more details about these errors I changed the default loggind of Tomcat to [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/). You can see the detailed instructions in [Apache Tomcat 7 (7.0.27) - Logging in Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html)

This is xml example for `log4j` that I was using:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p (%c.java:%L).%M - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <!-- CATALINA -->
  <logger name="org.apache.catalina.session">
    <level value="INFO" />
  </logger>
  <!-- TOMCAT -->
  </logger>
  <logger name="org.apache.jasper.compiler">
     <level value="INFO" />
  </logger>
  <!-- COMMONS -->
  <logger name="org.apache.commons.digester">
     <level value="INFO" />
  </logger>
  <root>
    <priority value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I hope that this can hep you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but does this mean its the best I can expect from java.util.logging? What if I do not want to configure log4j ? Is there any way by which I can still use java.util.logging(the default mechanism for logging) and have detailed logs available?

Comment: Tomcat by default defines five log handlers: one system wide  ConsoleHandler` and four `FileHandlers` defined in `CATALINA_HOME/conf/logging.properties`. Log level is set to `FINE` for all of them by default, so no messages logged at `FINER` or `FINEST` level will appear in any tomcat logs. You need add `logging.properties` in you WebApp for loggin with Java Logging framework.

Comment: Thanks for replying... You are right about the log level being set to FINE. I changed that to ALL but still I get the same type of logs. As far as the logging.properties file is concerned, the VM arguments ( Server Configuration in Eclipse) already specify the location of the logging.properties file. So why do I still need to add the logging.properties to my WebApp ?

Comment: You need put a `logging.properties` file and package it in `WEB-INF/classes` directory of your web application. Need define several handlers `handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler`, the default `.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler`, the level `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE`. and the formatter `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter`

Comment: If the Tomcat’s class loader sees the `logging.properties` file in the `WEB-INF/classes` of your web application, it will use it to configure logging for that web application, ignoring  `CATALINA_HOME/conf/logging.properties`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I removed the unused project that was referenced in **properties->Java Build Path->Projects**. It was showing that xyz(project Name) is missing.
I removed xyz.

Sometimes you can check in **properties->Java Build Path->libraries** whether any jar is missing. If so, you can add that jar from the classpath.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question